# coverity commit defects errors out with SSL solicitation failed: Server's SSL preference is "preferred"

Tags: ssl, coverity

Coverity instance details:

SA Version: 8.6
Connect: 8.7

While trying to upload defects to coverity instance, the following error is seen

Connecting to server xxx.xxx.com:9090
[ERROR] SSL solicitation failed: Server's SSL preference is "preferred" but SSL is not configured on the server.

Though we haven't configured https (ldap ssl) in our instance, cov commit defects fails with SSL error.

Is this something introduced newly in coverity connect 8.7? Or an environment settings issue?

Answer (score 0):

You may have configured Coverity Connect to use SSL.
Please check SSL settings in cim.properties

`grep commit.encryption <coverity-connect-install-path>/config/cim.properties`

`commit.encryption` should not be present or set to `none` if you do not intend to use SSL. Alternatively open server.xml to check if SSL is enabled. Connector section is commented when SSL is disabled

```
$ grep -A2 'Enable this connector to add SSL' <coverity-connect-install-path>/server/base/conf/server.xml
<!-- Enable this connector to add SSL support. -->
<!--
<Connector port="****"
```